# Local version different to deployed one

Tags: css, reactjs, localhost, web-deployment

I'm creating a react app and testing the css on localhost. When deployed, using the same browser (Chrome) and same screen size, the layout is completely different.
I've used Heroku and Netlify to deploy and both change the original version. 
The icons appear way bigger, but other changes like colours or fonts are still applied correctly.

Anyone knows why this happens? Anyone knows a solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a viewport meta tag in your html? E.g. `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">`. Is all you css loaded if you open up the network tab in the developer tools?

Comment: Yes, I've got the viewport, and yes, all the css is loaded. I can see it all, but it does not seem to 'read' it all. It only seems to affect sizes. Colours and fonts are changed straight away.

Comment: have you cleared your cache or updated your cache buster?

Comment: Yes. Even on incognito mode.